# NGB Modal Overriding CSS

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I am using NGB modal in my project in multiple components, and I want to style the modal differently in each component. I have to access some elements like ".modal" which I can't access directly via HTML, hence I have to use ::ng-deep. Now if I style each modal specifically, I can't because of ng-deep( which applies styles to all modals having .modal class).
If I includes encapsulation, then modal gets backdrop which disable clicking the background around modal:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

[image]
I have used :host but it didn't helped as :

```
:host ::ng-deep .modal {
        position: fixed !important;
        right:0 ;
        z-index: 1050 ;
        left: 37%;
        right: 100;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 25% !important;
        }
```

Looking forward to see your responses.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the NgbModalOptions properties is windowClass. Set it in the second parameter of NgbModal.open.

```
.mymodal {
  width:25%;
}
```

Then

```
const modalRef = oNgbModal.open(myModalComponent, {windowClass:'mymodal',backdrop:'static'});
```

Setting backdrop to 'static' will prevent closing on click.
All these are on the api documentation page.

Comment: `this.modalService.open(Content,{backdrop: false,windowClass:'custom'});`                                             I have tried this option as above, but it does not remove the backdrop, which prevents me from clicking around the modal. I have to keep the background clickable.

Comment: Doing backdrop:'static' does my background blur and so does unclickable! , just like setting it true.